# PDO Statement not executing, no errors

Tags: php, pdo

I've been trying to get this single PDO Statement to work and it just does not want to execute!

I have hundreds of similar statements and they all execute just fine, but this single one simply fails to execute. There aren't even any error messages to show. Either I'm overlooking something really simple, or there's something really wrong.

```
<?php 

require_once('inc/connect_dbo.php');

//Add dummy client
$first_name = "John";
$first_name = "Smith";
$client_type = "individual";
$individual_email = 'john.smith@email.com';
$gender = 'male';
$primary_phone = '1234567890';
$address = '1 Yonge St, Toronto, ON';

$query = $dbo->prepare("INSERT INTO clients SET account_id = ?, first_name = ?, last_name = ?, type = ?, email = ?, gender = ?, primary_phone = ?, address = ?");
$query->execute(array($account_id, $first_name, $last_name, $client_type, $individual_email, $gender, $primary_phone, $address));

$client_id = $dbo->lastInsertId();

print_r($dbo->errorInfo());
echo $client_id;
exit;

?>
```

The output from the errorInfo is emtpy:

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you check the return value of execute()? Or else do you configure PDO to raise exceptions on error? The fact that you have called lastInsertId() before you look at the error info may be obscuring an error caused by the INSERT.

Comment: I recommend displaying errors as well. There are a couple of undefined variables there.

Comment: I tried switching the order of the lastInsertId and echoing the errors but it made no difference. Also $account_id is defined earlier on in the code, not included in the snippet. What's strange is that when I try to insert the $account_id alone, without all the other fields it works like a charm!

Comment: I think I need to kick myself one in the rear. Turns out I defined $first_name twice, and tried to insert $last_name, which was undefined. Eeekh!